# Add custom stylesheet for Custom Post Types

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I've created a custom archive page for a custom post type I've also created. I would like to style only this Custom Archive page. I've tried to create a function inside functions.php but it doesn't work.

My question is : how do I use a custom stylesheet for this archive page and not on the other ones ?

Thanks

```
function interviewlist_style() {
if ( is_page_template('archive-interview.php') )
wp_enqueue_style('Archive Interviews', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/archive_interviews.css');
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'interviewlist_style', 1);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I've understood the question correctly, you've created a template for your custom post type archive.

The conditional you're using would apply if you were viewing a page that had been assigned a custom template with the file name 'archive-interview.php'. As you're dealing with an archive, not a page, you need to use a different function.

Replace:

```
if ( is_page_template('archive-interview.php') )
```

With:

```
if ( is_post_type_archive( 'interview' ) )
```

This will evaluate to true if you're viewing the archive for a custom post type named 'interview'.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_post_type_archive